# Type mismatch. Required: Fragment Found: DashboardFragment.Companion

Tags: android

I got this error while using the replace function to change the frame of the main Activity with the fragment that I created it shows type mismatch required fragment found **DashboardFragmentComapnion**

```
package com.shivanshu.bookhub

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout
    lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    lateinit var frameLayout: FrameLayout
    lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout)
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
        setUpToolbar()

        val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this@MainActivity,
            drawerLayout,
            R.string.open_drawer,
            R.string.close_drawer
        )

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.dashboard -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.frameLayout, DashboardFragment).commit()
                }
                R.id.profile ->{
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Profile Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                }
                R.id.about_app -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"About Section Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                }
                R.id.favourites -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Favourites Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                }
            }


            return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

    }

    fun setUpToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.title = "Toolbar Title"
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        val id = item.itemId

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START )
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

The fragment file:

```
package com.shivanshu.bookhub

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [DashboardFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard2, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment DashboardFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
                DashboardFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

I implement the NavigationDrawer having various menu items when I click on the dashboard menu item it will open the dashboard fragment I created

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an instance of DashboardFragment to replace function.

```
val dashboardFragmentInctance = DashboardFragment.newInstance("param","param")
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.frameLayout, dashboardFragmentInctance).commit()
```

Comment: thanks that works but why we passsed the strings param param

Comment: Your fragment code is generated by ide and just for a sample to show how to instantiate fragments and how to pass data to fragments(best practice). you can delete it.